# Combining Outputs With Java

Tags: java

I'm working through an old MIT course trying to learn java in my spare time. This early assignment is about calculating pay with overtime. How do I produce output that combines the output for each employee so I get output like this:

> Employee 1 gets paid $262.5 but gets paid below the minimum wage at $7.5
>   Employee 3 works 73.0 hours which is over the legal limit and gets paid $895.0

```
public class FooCorporation {

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {

        double[] basePay = { 7.50, 8.20, 10.00 };
        double[] hoursWorked = { 35, 47, 73 };
        double[] totalPay = new double[basePay.length];
        String[] Employee = { "Employee 1", "Employee 2", "Employee 3" };
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < basePay.length; x++) {
                if (basePay[x] < 8.0) {
                    System.out.println(Employee[x] + " gets paid below the minimum wage at $" + basePay[x]);
                }
                if (hoursWorked[x] > 60) {
                    System.out.println(Employee[x] + " works " + hoursWorked[x] +  " hours which is over the legal limit" );
                }
                if (hoursWorked[x] > 40) {
                    totalPay[x] = (40.0 * basePay[x]) + ((hoursWorked[x] - 40.0) * (basePay[x] * 1.5));
                } else if (hoursWorked[x] < 40.0)
                    totalPay[x] = hoursWorked[x] * basePay[x];
                System.out.println(Employee[x] + " gets paid $" + totalPay[x]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (hoursWorked[x] > 40)` will overwrite `if (hoursWorked[x] > 60)` unless you make it an `else if`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ (preferably 10 lines or less) to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

List all cases and conditions:

Have all individual data in simple variables:

```
double pay = basePay[x];
```

For that I would suggest using plurals for arrays, singular for the element.

Start with the criteria:

```
boolean underpaid = pay < 8.0;
boolean overworked = hoursWorked[x] > 60;
...
```

Then combine those criteria (`if (underpaid && overworked)`) ensuring
you cover all cases and then use formatted printing.

```
if (...) {
    System.out.printf("%s gets paid $%.2f but"
        + " gets paid below the minimum wage at $%f%n", employee, pay, min);
} else if (...) {
    System.out.printf("%s works %.1f hours which is over the legal limit"
        + " and gets paid $%.2f%n", employee, hours, pay);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will output something similar to what you are looking for you must either output the total pay before the minimum wage and overworked statements or vice versa. You cannot have it one way for employee 1 and the other for employee 3.

To combine output use a print statement instead of println for the total pay output. This will not create a new line after the output therefore combining it with the subsequent print statements.

```
public class FooCorporation {

     public static void main(String[] arguments) {

         double[] basePay = { 7.50, 8.20, 10.00 };
         double[] hoursWorked = { 35, 47, 73 };
         double[] totalPay = new double[basePay.length];
         String[] Employee = { "Employee 1", "Employee 2", "Employee 3" };

         for (int x = 0; x < basePay.length; x++) {
              if (hoursWorked[x] > 40) {
                totalPay[x] = (40.0 * basePay[x]) + ((hoursWorked[x] - 40.0) * (basePay[x] * 1.5));
            } else if (hoursWorked[x] < 40.0)
                totalPay[x] = hoursWorked[x] * basePay[x];
            System.out.print("Employee[x] + " gets paid $" + totalPay[x]);

            if (basePay[x] < 8.0) {
                System.out.println(" but gets paid below the minimum wage at $" + basePay[x]);
            }
            if (hoursWorked[x] > 60) {
                System.out.println(Employee[x] + " but works " + hoursWorked[x] +  " hours which is over the legal limit" );
            }

        }
    }
}
```